# QT installation - OpenGL (No ANGLE)

Tags: qt, angle, qtopengl

I have installed the last version of QT but it seems that this one contains some DirectX calls, so I expect that the default installer use ANGLE !

I wish to install a 100% openGL version, but I can't find one !

Any idea ?

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All official binary packages are configured with

```
  -opengl dynamic
```

which means that programs can either use the installed (desktop) OpenGL driver, DirectX (via ANGLE), or an OpenGL emulation in software (Mesa) as OpenGL backends. If you always want to use Desktop OpenGL, you can force this by

1. Setting the environment variable `QT_OPENGL` to `desktop`
2. Calling `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseDesktopOpenGL)`

See also http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#graphics-drivers .

If you want a Qt version that *only* supports the Desktop OpenGL backend, you have to build Qt from sources.